# Async in mapDispatchToProps - wrapper to ensure everything dispatches before rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

The result I want is my component to not render unless all the async function have dispatched. I'm using this as a wrapper to make sure everything has dispatched. I've tried two ways:

1. call everything in `componentWillMount` and use `setState` to set `loaded = true`. I can then render the component based on my state's loaded key.

   ```
   ajax = async () => {
     try{
       const { dispatch } = this.props;
       dispatch(loadPack('ars'));
       dispatch(loadPack('acr'));
       await dispatch(loadProds());
       await dispatch(loadRepls());
       await dispatch(checkEligibile());
       }catch (e) { console.log(e)}
    }

    componentWillMount() {
      this.ajax().then(() => {
        this.setState({ loaded: true });
      });
    }

   render() {
    const { loaded } = this.state;
    return loaded ? <Component/> : null;
   }
   ```

This gets the desired results, except I see this error:

> ExceptionsManager.js:71 Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting
>   component. This usually means you called setState, replaceState, or
>   forceUpdate on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.

2. I tried dispatching in `mapDispatchToProps`. Ideally `loaded` should return true and I should see `this.props.loaded = true` to load my component. However, I'm receiving a Promise and not the result.

I'm feeling stuck here and not sure what else to try. Any suggestions?

```
const loadAsync = async dispatch => {
  dispatch(loadPack('ars'));
  dispatch(loadPack('acr'));
  await dispatch(loadProds());
  await dispatch(loadRepls());
  await dispatch(checkEligibile());
  return true
 };

 export const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
   loaded: loadAsync(dispatch),
 });
```

Comment: try `componentDidMount` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using redux, you have a global redux state. So after all dispatch, dispatch one more action that toogle a reducer state to true which indicate that all the actions has been dispatched.

In component, use dispatchStateToProps method to convert reducer state into props and then use that prop to check weather all the actions has been dispatched or not. It should roughly look something like this

```
ajax = async () => {
  try{
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    dispatch(loadPack('ars'));
    dispatch(loadPack('acr'));
    await dispatch(loadProds());
    await dispatch(loadRepls());
    await dispatch(checkEligibile());
    // Add one more action here
    await dispatch(everythingDispatched());
    }catch (e) { console.log(e)}
 }
```

Then a reducer state that keep track of that

```
dispatchTrackerReducer.js
switch(action.type){
  case "everythingDispatched" :
       everythingDispatched: true
       break;
}
```

Then in component use mapStateToProps  like this

```
render() {
 const { everythingDispatched } = this.props;
 return everythingDispatched ? <Component/> : null;
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
  return {
       everythingDispatched:state.dispatchTrackerReducer.everythingDispatche
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I wonder if I should pull everything out of componentWillMount and put the other functions in everythingDispatched. That way this component only has to dispatch everythingDispatched and not a large group of dispatches. But, I'm thinking adding all these async functions to everythingDispatched wouldn't be a pure function anymore and would be an anti-redux pattern. Do you have any ideas how to refactor the grouping of dispatches so that this component only dispatches everythingDispatched?

Comment: Both the ways are fine. Though i usually prefer dispatching everything individually in component like the way you are doing right now. That thing help because by just looking at the component file i get the idea what this component is dispatching which helps me to understand the component.

Comment: If you combine them and dispatch only one then you will put them in different file. So you will have to jump to different file everytime you want to know what this component is dispatching.

Comment: However this is just my preference. You do what suits best for you.